# Opposite of a function that surrounds selection with span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey Guys I got a function like this:

```
  define(function () {
  'use strict';
  var sel, range, span;
  return function () {
    span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = 'highlight';

    if (window.getSelection) {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        range.surroundContents(span);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
       }
     }
   };
 });
```

It bascially surrounds my selection with a span. I would like to have an opposite of this method removes the span from the selected text. For example

I have a div:

```
<div>some text in here</div>
```

Lets say I applied the above on the word "here" of above:

```
<div>some text in <span class="highlight">here</span></div>
```

I would like to have a method that removed the span from the word if I have it highlighted again.

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tagged jQuery. You can simply use combination of [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('.highlight').contents().unwrap()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/vKKhL/)